# How to remove disable attribute from a button in form-mini

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to remove disable from a button in `form-mini.phtml` but couldn't find a way through jquery/javascript. I know it gets enabled after adding a few characters, but by default, it remains disabled.

As I'm creating my own theme from scratch, I want that `disabled` attribute to be removed at all times for now.

```
<button
   type="submit"
   title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Search')) ?>"
   class="action search"
   aria-label="Search"
>
   <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Search')) ?></span>
/button>
```

I tried by `$('.action.search').removeAttr("disabled")` and `$('.action.search').prop('disabled', false)` but couldn't find any luck.

When I removed `type="submit"` from the `button`, the disabled removed as well. And I got an error `TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'disabled')` from Magento. So I guess it's somehow connected to `type="submit"`.

I was wondering if there is a way to manipulate the javascript of `form-mini.phtml` as well or what would be the better way to achieve this.

Please, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, the `disabled` attribute from the search button (after page loaded) does not exists in vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/templates/form.mini.phtml.

The code adding the `disable` attribute to the search button located in JS file: vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/web/js/form-mini.js

There are 2 places set the `disable` attribute to `true` that will add the `disable` attribute to the search button:

- in `_create` function
- in `_onPropertyChange` function

To remove the `disable` attribute from the search button in form-mini you have to set the `disable` attribute to `false`. To achieve this, the **best** way is extending `form-mini.js` by using a mixin in a custom module:

Step 1: Create the `requirejs-config.js` in your custom module, file path is app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Search/js/form-mini': {
                'VendorName_ModuleName/js/form-mini-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Step 2: Create the form-mini minxin file:

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    var quickSearchWidgetMixin = {
        /** @inheritdoc */
        _create: function () {
            this._super();
            this.submitBtn.disabled = false; // Customize to remove the disabled attribute
        },

        /** @inheritdoc */
        _onPropertyChange: function () {
            this._super();
            this.submitBtn.disabled = false; // Customize to remove the disabled attribute
        }
    };

    return function (targetWidget) {
        $.widget('mage.quickSearch', targetWidget, quickSearchWidgetMixin);

        return $.mage.quickSearch;
    };
});
```

Step 3: Run the following commands to re-deploy static content:

```
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend pub/static/frontend
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f --area frontend
```

Magento has a document for Javascript mixins, you can take a look https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/javascript/mixins/

Comment: Thank you so much for showing me how to extend the existing js. It worked, but I'm getting an error in the console that `refused to apply script because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`.

Comment: Is there something I need to do after adding `config` object in `require-config.js`?

Comment: It's giving me a 404 not found error from require.js.

Comment: I've updated the answer to add the re-deploy static content step. Please do that and verify.

Comment: I ran the step 3 commands, but my issue still persists. The errors are still showing up. Although the code is working, do you know what could be the reason of that?

Comment: 1. Check if `pub/static/.htaccess is exists or not. If not, you can download or create one with content at  https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.5/pub/static/.htaccess . Remember change **2.4.5** in the link to your magento version. Then re-deploy static content again.

Comment: 2. If after you have done the above point (1), the issue still exists, check if you or your teammate modify any **.less** files, it may have an issue. And certainly, every time you modify .less, JS files, you have to redeploy static content if you don't setup a tool that supports watching .less files and auto-applied the new changes.

Comment: I checked it exists. I guess the Htaccess isn't the issue. The problem is when we deploy, the overridden file isn't being created under `pub/static`.

Comment: So whenever you deploy static content manually from command line, you have to remove **pub/static/frontend/ and var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend** folders (in case you deploy frontend theme) before running the deploy command  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy